# PrimeNg Tree Add Custom property to TreeNode [Angular5]

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I want to add custom Property to TreeNode of PrimeNg Tree angular such as:

`TreeNode.id = "DemoId"` but it is giving me error "id" is unknown property of TreeNode.

So I wanted to know what is correct way to add other attributes to TreeNode in primeNg tree for angular5.

Comment: You can only add those attributes which are defined in the library , not custom One , IMO. But you can use local variable to achieve something

Answer (score 0):

`TreeNode` interface doesn't have a property called 'id'. you can only set values to properties given by the `TreeNode` interface. https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/common/treenode.ts

Answer (score 0):

we did it this way:

```
export interface NavigatableTreeNode<T = TreeNodeType> extends TreeNode<T> {
    id: TreeNodeId
    navigationPath: TreeNodeId[]
    children?: NavigatableTreeNode<T>[]
}
```

But I think in most cases the ID you need could be set in data and is not required in the nodes. Example: `dataKey` uses the given key from data.